# Check if element exists in HashSet by its hash

Tags: java, hashcode, hashset

Can I check if an object is in a `HashSet` if I have only the object's hash code, but not the object itself?

Answer (score 10):

You can't, since the `hashCode` is only used to locate the bin in which the object is stored within the `HashSet`. There may be multiple elements in the same bin, and `HashSet` uses `equals` to determine if the searched element exists in the bin that the `hashCode` was mapped to.

The bin may contain multiple elements having the same `hashCode`, so knowing only the `hashCode` is not enough.

Comment: Could you not iteratively compare the contents' respective hashCodes against the known hashCode? Not necessarily elegant, but doable

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 What if more than one element has the same hashCode?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a special object, something like this

```
int hashCode = 1;  // your 
new Object() {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is clever, but it depends on the set calling `cleverObject.equals(objectInSet)`. If there's any set implementation out there that tests `objectInSet.equals(cleverObject)` instead, or if the implementation in java.util ever changes, this will break. In other words, you're violating the `equals` contract, and you might get away with it for a while, but it might come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant. Both equals and hashcode are required for finding an object in a hashed collection. The hashcode method tells which bucket to find the object in and the equals method finds the object in the bucket.

A real world example would be a house with many people in it. If you tell me to go find someone in some house, I am going to ask you two questions :

1. What house do I go to?
2. Who do I find?

Here (1) will be answered by hashcode and (2) will be answered by equals method.

Answer (score 1):

A `hashCode` is not a uniquely identifying property, so no.

Answer (score 1):

No, because 2 objects can have the same hashcode. The unicity of objects in a `Set` (or keys in a `Map`) is checked against `hashCode()` **and** `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

All Objects have method hashCode(), called by HashSet, HashMap, ecc..

You can override this method to define your own logic

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return <<MY CODE HERE>>;
    }
```

or, more simple, iterate your HashSet and check hashCode() value

```
int myHash = 123;
for(Object o:mySet){
  if(myHash == o.hashCode()){
    // do something..
  }
}
```